# Only run condor jobs if less than RAM threshold is used

Tags: condor

I have an execute host with 132 slots and condor will happily run 132 jobs there. But depending on the jobs those 132 can use all the RAM and cause swapping and eventually trashing. How can I set a config
option that says, 'do not run jobs if the RAM used is more then nnGB'?

I have read https://htcondor-wiki.cs.wisc.edu/index.cgi/wiki?p=HowToLimitMemoryUsage
but it does not say how to do this.

When I say RAM used I am taking about the number I see in the used
column in free:

```
$ free -mh
               total        used        free      shared buff/cache   available
Mem:           125G         44G         18G         19M         63G         79G
```

Comment: I don't have a cluster I can administrate to give you an actual answer, but I think you want to look into customizing the [START Policy criteria](http://research.cs.wisc.edu/htcondor/manual/v8.6/3_5Configuration_Macros.html#SECTION00458000000000000000). The macro for physical RAM in MB is [`$(DETECTED_MEMORY)`](http://research.cs.wisc.edu/htcondor/manual/v8.6/3_3Introduction_Configurati.html#SECTION004312000000000000000).

Comment: But does that change dynamically as RAM is consumed to give the amount available or is it the static value of the total RAM?

Comment: I imagine you'd need to use a locally evaluated START policy expression that mixes the machine's current state (from its ClassAds) with that max  memory macro, i.e. test if the currently available RAM is x% of the total and evaluate START to `False` if so. If I were able to test these statements I'd be writing an answer rather than pointing you to documentation. http://research.cs.wisc.edu/htcondor/manual/v8.6/3_7Policy_Configuration.html#SECTION00471100000000000000

Comment: 2 questions: 1) What in the ClassAd shows the current amount of RAM used or available? When I look at the ClassAd while jobs are running I do not see any values related to the memory changing - they always seem to show that total RAM. 2) Assuming there is such a value in the ClassAd that give that, how do I reference it in the policy expression?

Answer (score 1):

When HTCondor does matchmaking, it takes the value of `MEMORY` into account. This value is adjustable.

For example, you can set the following on your worker node to reserve 2GB:

`MEMORY = $(DETECTED_MEMORY) - 2048`